# Drupal 7 : Limit number of records in a view and then render programmatically

Tags: views

The question is similar to this one :

[Views programmatically limit results](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24523/views-programmatically-limit-results)

But i still cannot limit number of items in my view. The ways i already tried :

```
$args = array();
$view = views_get_view('news_details');
$view->set_display('default');
$view->display_handler->set_option('items_per_page', 3);
$view->execute();
print $view->preview('default', $args);

$view = views_get_view('news_details');
$view->set_display('default');
$view->set_items_per_page(3);
$view->execute();

$view = views_get_view('news_details');
$view->set_display('default');
$view->set_arguments(array('all'));
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;
$view->display['default']->handler->options['items_per_page'] = 3;
$view->display['default']->handler->options['title'] = $title;
$view->display['default']->handler->options['display_options']['use_pager'] = FALSE;
$view->execute();
```

Whatever i am doing :

- $view->result always returns 1 item
- $view->preview() always returns all items

According to the answer above it seems like i need to apply this method to pager, not view, in this case how do i get access to this pager, **could somebody provide working example of how to correctly limit items in view**?

**Got it :**

I had "Display Items" set to "Display All" in pager settings of my View. It, according to Views, does not allow to filter view rows.